# Evicting doesn't mean deproxying?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Why evicted object still remains as hibernate proxy?

I am invoking session.clear();

and in the next line I see on my debugger that one of the objects is still a hibernate proxy.

Is there any good explanation for such hibernate behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

session.evict does can not alter the content of the variable which is copied on the stack when calling evict hence the variable still points to the proxy.

AFAIK to **ensure** that you get **reference equality** it will return the initialised proxy evertime you session.get with the same id.